# How to tell the Rust compiler that type annotations are not actually needed?

Tags: generics, rust

```
struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait> {
    inner: T,
}

impl<T: MyTrait> MyStruct<T> {
    const MYCONST: u32 = 42;

    pub fn x() {
        println!("x!");
    }
}

pub trait MyTrait {}
```

Accessing either `MYCONST` or `x()` requires a trait.  If none are provided, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:42:5
   |
42 |     MyStruct::x();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
```

or

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:42:20
   |
42 |     println!("{}", MyStruct::MYCONST);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler to ignore the need for type annotations here?

Comment: Yes it's needed... why not just move it outside ? or put in the trait definition ?

Comment: What do you mean, "ignore the need for type annotations"? Should the compiler pick a `T` for you? Or do you just want to know *how to annotate* the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to "**Why** is the type annotation needed?" consider the following code:

```
struct MyStruct<T> {
    inner: T,
}

impl MyStruct<i32> {
    const MYCONST: u32 = 42;

    pub fn x() {
        println!("i32!");
    }
}

impl MyStruct<i64> {
    const MYCONST: u32 = 64;

    pub fn x() {
        println!("i64!");
    }
}


fn main() {
    MyStruct::x();
}
```

Should it print `i32` or `i64`?

Answer (score 3):

The type annotations **are** needed — there *is no type called `MyStruct`*. This has nothing to do with traits, either:

```
struct MyStruct<T> {
    inner: T,
}

impl<T> MyStruct<T> {
    const MYCONST: u32 = 42;

    pub fn x() {
        println!("x!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    MyStruct::x();
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:14:6
   |
14 |      MyStruct::x();
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`
```

A type definition with a generic isn't actually a type, it's a *type constructor*. You *must* fill in the generics to get a type in order to access associated items.